# Multi-threading with WinApi in C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I've been struggling with multi-threading for a while now...managed to work it out last night on my current program, what I wanted is to have a simple timer running while I'm still able to work with my application.

I used msdn [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esszf9hw.aspx).

I managed to make it work fine ( or at least I think it works fine ) with this code:

```
case ID_MENUBUTTON0:

        hRunMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, NULL);
        _beginthread(Sistem::timeFrame, 0, NULL);
        break;

case ID_MENUBUTTON4:
        ReleaseMutex(hRunMutex);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
```

Sistem::timeFrame func calculates time with intervals of 100ms `Sleep(100);` and outputs it in a static window and updates the window every 100ms.

Now what I wanted to ask since I didn't really understand all the fuss about this is why is there so many extra stuff ?
Such as `WaitForSingleObject`, I've seen a lot of it but can't figure out it's practical use. Is there something I should watch out for except for `ReleaseMutex()` ?

Comment: `I've been struggling with multi-threading for a while now...`  Mutithreaded programming is not trivial.  Your small example has a lot of issues with it as it stands now, such as making sure that the Mutex is actually released (what if `ID_MENUBUTTON4` is never executed?).  Instead of writing your own code, I highly suggest looking and learning from real example programs and read up on topics and books on multithreaded programming (and no, MSDN does not teach you multithreaded programming).

Comment: I've added ReleaseMutex to all exit stations if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObjects are used to make a thread wait until another thread has done something. The practical use is coordination, like don't land the plane until the wheels are down.